# Environment variable seems not set while it is in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, environment-variables

I have a shell script file `./bin/postactivate` with following content:

```
#!/bin/sh

export STATIC_ROOT="/webapps/tsango/static/"
export MEDIA_ROOT="/webapps/tsango/media/"
export DATABASE_NAME="tsango"
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="tsango.settings.vagrant"
export DATABASE_PASSWORD="password"
export BROKER_URL="amqp://tsango:password@localhost/tsango"
export DATABASE_USER="tsango"
```

I execute it with `sudo sh ./bin/postactivate` command. The command seems to run properly, i.e. no output from the command line.

However, when I use `printenv` to see the list of environment variables, none of the variables of the script is set.

I'm probably missing something... Can you tell me what?

Comment: why use `sh` to run it? You have a hash bash slash bin slash sh? Now set the execute bit, and you don't need to run it with `sh`.

Comment: Do you mean in the script like you have put in the title (but not shown in your code), or after the script (as would cause this problem)?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Thanks for your answer. In fact I learnt that environment variables are linked to a process. That was the root cause of the issue.

Comment: I did not provide an answer. Just two comments: one a side note, and one a question.

Comment: Environment variables are inherited by child process.

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke the script as

```
source bin/postactivate
```

A process has environment variables. Let us assume your shell has a process id of 1003. You invoke `sudo sh ./bin/postactivate`. PID 1003 forks to create a new process, say 1108. process 1108 calls `exec` to change itself into `sudo`. `sudo` then changes itself into `sh` to process your script. So PID 1108 sets the environment variables **for itself** such as STATIC_ROOT. It then exits. Your shell (PID 1003) which was waiting for 1108 prints a new prompt, but nothing has changed in the environment for PID 1003.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a real dummy to linux... and wasn't even suspecting that environment variables are linked to processes.